# How do you access the high speed SRAM in ARM CPUs from user-mode code on WinCE?

Tags: windows-ce, arm

When writing embedded ARM code, it's easy to access to the built-in zero wait state memory to accelerate your application.  Windows CE doesn't expose this to user-mode applications, but there is probably a way to do it.  The internal SRAM is usually used for the video buffer, but there's usually some left over.  Anyone know how to do it?

Thanks,
Larry B.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't access the high speed ram from usermode-processes.

The only way to get access to it on a WindowsCE-OS is to write a driver, map the fixed address of the TCM into the user-mode process address space and pass it to the user-mode process.